# How can I do modeling in reverse by parsing a C program and turning it in to a circuit diagram to be displayed

Tags: c, parsing, modeling, circuit

How can I do modeling in reverse by parsing a C program and turning it in to a circuit diagram to be displayed.

Example

[image]

[image]

Except this is psedocode.

Comment: While this sounds like a potentially interesting question, what you're asking sounds VERY open-ended.

Comment: Unless you have a lot of source code at your command, and/or have a lot of hardware specific information, you're not going to be able to do this for many library calls.

Comment: I suspect Googling for "SystemC" will give you some ideas. Like Verilog and VHDL, it was originally targeted primarily as simulation, but there is now a synthesizable subset -- an ability to write code in SystemC (which is really C++ with a class library) and compile it to an actual circuit you can then put into something like a CPLD, FPGA, or possibly an ASIC.

Comment: "Clonsed as not a real question"? That's unreasonable.  As a compiler persion, I think about programs as *circuits* of dataflow and operators.  See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a first guess I would say you need to construct a C compiler from scratch (or co-opt one) and inspect the parse tree looking for constructs that you can represent with your list of simple symbols. Once you have done that you need a rendering engine to take the list of detected constructs and lay them out in a pretty picture.

Some random observations:

1. There are many C concepts that can't be rendered in a simplistic manner (ie pointers)
2. Making your pic look pretty will be a bitch
3. [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) would be a good place to look for ideas (the do a nice function call structure graph)
4. Going off on a tangent you might like to look at [IEC 61131-3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEC_61131-3)  programming languages for PLCs.  These are graphically laid out languages that provide 5 different ways of describing program control and focus heavily on representations of logic